# Make website load faster

Tags: html, css, django

I'm working on my first web app (www.shopperspoll.com). It's a Django based facebook app and I was wondering how I can go about making the pages load faster. Sorry that the main page is a mess now, started making some major changes yesterday, but you'll notice that it takes a really long for the page to load. I was wondering if that has something to do with the way I've set Django up on my host, or something else. If you could give me some pointers on how I can go about making it faster, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of points need to be considered for better page loads
1) Put all javascripts externally, and always load scripts at the end of the page (in footer).
2) Always minify javscripts and css.
3) Merge all CSS and javascript into one file during load.
4) Make use of browser caching (for css, javascript and images).
5) Host static files like css, javascript and images over different domain.  (Ex : static. shopperspoll.com )
6) Use tools likes firebug & yslow to check the load time.
7) use cdn.

Also refer this URL (better web performance from yahoo) :  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As for what [Aby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616666/aby) said, I'd also suggest using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) - [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) offer a free tier for theirs which could be useful for you whilst early in growth. The majority of speeding up is already covered in Aby's answer, but once you've done that, a CDN can help with putting files geographically closer to your users.